# Decode an Unicode escaped character from PyQt5 QLabel widget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to read in a text sequence from a QLineEdit that might contain Unicode escape sequence and print it out to a QLabel and display the proper character in PyQt5 and Python 3.4.

I tried many different things that I read here on stackoverflow but couldn't find a working solution for Python 3.

```
def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
    text = self.lineEdit.text()
    self.label.setText(text)
```

Now if I do something like this:

```
    decodedText = str("dsfadsfa \u2662  \u8f1d  \u2662").encode("utf-8")
    self.label.setText(text.decode("utf-8")
```

This does print out the proper characters. If I apply the same to the above method I get the escaped sequences. 
I don't get what is the difference between the str() returned by QLineEdit's text() and the str("\u2662"). Why does the one encode the characters properly and the other one doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `"\u2662"` isn't a string with a Unicode escape, it's a string *literal* with a Unicode escape. A string with the same Unicode escape would be `"\\u2662"`.

```
3>> codecs.getdecoder('unicode-escape')('\\u2662')
('♢', 6)
```